# Azerothcore - Autobalance DungeonScaleDownXP add additional check for solo player

Tags: azerothcore

I am currently running the autobalance module on my [AzerothCore](https://github.com/azerothcore/azerothcore-wotlk) server. I want to enable the `DungeonScaleDownXP`:

```
#
#     AutoBalance.DungeonScaleDownXP
#        Decrease individual player's amount of XP gained during a dungeon to match the
#        amount of XP gained during a full group run. Example: In a 5-man group, you
#        earn 1/5 of the total XP per kill, but if you solo the dungeon with
#        AutoBalance.DungeonScaleDownXP = 0, you will earn 5/5 of the total XP.
#        With the option enabled, you will earn 1/5.
#        Default:     0 (1 = ON, 0 = OFF)

AutoBalance.DungeonScaleDownXP = 0
```

But I would like to slightly modify it for solo players. I would like to make it so they get 2.5 times XP. But if its a group of two or more use the normal scaled-down XP. I believe this is the section I would need to modify:

```cpp
void OnGiveXP(Player* player, uint32& amount, Unit* victim) override
{
  if (victim && DungeonScaleDownXP)
  {
    Map* map = player->GetMap();

    if (map->IsDungeon())
    {
      // Ensure that the players always get the same XP, even when entering the dungeon alone
      uint32 maxPlayerCount = ((InstanceMap*)sMapMgr->FindMap(map->GetId(), map->GetInstanceId()))->GetMaxPlayers();
      uint32 currentPlayerCount = map->GetPlayersCountExceptGMs();
      amount *= (float)currentPlayerCount / maxPlayerCount;
    }
  }
}
```

Just not sure how to go about it. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up figuring out a solution to this. First i added a new option in the conf:

```
#
#     AutoBalance.DungeonScaleDownXP.rate.solo
#        Set individual player's amount of XP gained during a dungeon run.
#        AutoBalance.DungeonScaleDownXP = 1 you will earn 1/5 of the total XP as a solo player
#        modifying this rate with allow you to set how much XP a solo player will receive 
#        Default:     1.0

AutoBalance.DungeonScaleDownXP.rate.solo = 1.0
```

Next i added to the static float the new option:

```
static float globalRate, healthMultiplier, manaMultiplier, armorMultiplier, damageMultiplier, MinHPModifier, MinManaModifier, MinDamageModifier, DungeonScaleDownXPSoloRate,
InflectionPoint, InflectionPointRaid, InflectionPointRaid10M, InflectionPointRaid25M, InflectionPointHeroic, InflectionPointRaidHeroic, InflectionPointRaid10MHeroic, InflectionPointRaid25MHeroic, BossInflectionMult;
```

Then set the new float option to read from the config:

```
DungeonScaleDownXPSoloRate = sConfigMgr->GetFloatDefault("AutoBalance.DungeonScaleDownXP.rate.solo", 1.0f);
```

Then added an if to check the `currentPlayerCount`:

```cpp
void OnGiveXP(Player* player, uint32& amount, Unit* victim) override
        {
            if (victim && DungeonScaleDownXP)
            {
                Map* map = player->GetMap();

                if (map->IsDungeon())
                {
                    // Ensure that the players always get the same XP, even when entering the dungeon alone
                    uint32 maxPlayerCount = ((InstanceMap*)sMapMgr->FindMap(map->GetId(), map->GetInstanceId()))->GetMaxPlayers();
                    uint32 currentPlayerCount = map->GetPlayersCountExceptGMs();
                    if (currentPlayerCount == 1)
                    {
                    amount *= (float)currentPlayerCount / maxPlayerCount * DungeonScaleDownXPSoloRate;
                    }
                    else
                    {
                    amount *= (float)currentPlayerCount / maxPlayerCount;
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Now i can adjust the xp rate in the config.